# MySQL query returning 0 rows when searching with lat and lng decimals

Tags: mysql, sql, select, geospatial

I'm trying to execute this query:

```
SELECT  `venues` . * 
FROM  `venues` 
WHERE  `lat` >= 39.847991180331
AND  `lng` >= -86.332592054637
AND  `lat` <= 40.137846252794
AND  `lng` <= -85.954901904578
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Here is the table structure of the lat and lng fields and a sample row, it should be returning AT LEAST 1 row

```
lng decimal(65,15)                              
lat decimal(65,15)

Name                  Lng                   Lat
Ambre Blends Studio   -86.143746979607530   39.875314973898870
```

However when I execure the above query it returns no rows. What's the problem here?

Comment: Something else must be funny as it [works on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8245/1)

Comment: What else could be funny? It isn't dependent on anything other than what I have in my query right?

Comment: Just to check, it also works on [MySQL 5.1.61](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/d8245/1). Not sure if it's a bug with the version you have though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm always circumspect about floating point equality and inequality operations and MySQL has had a history of problems in the past with this sort of thing (I'm not sure which version you're using but there were some changes made around 503/505).

The first thing I would do is debug the actual statement. Start with:

```
select venues.* from venues
 where name like 'Ambre%'
```

and ensure you only get one row (you may have to tweak the `where` clause if there's lots of rows starting with `Ambre`).

Then add the other subclauses one at a time until the row doesn't appear. The first would be:

```
select venues.* from venues
 where name like 'Ambre%'
   and lat >= 39.847991180331
```

Once you establish *which* condition is causing the `select` to fail, you can start looking into why.

Comment: The problem is different than I expected originally, I'm outputting the query that Zend Framework is creating 

    SELECT `venues`.* FROM `venues` WHERE `lat` >= 39.730387437667 AND `lng` >= -86.332592054637 AND `lat` <= 40.020242510131 AND `lng` <= -85.954901904578

which is returning the correct number of rows, when it's executed through Zend (using PDO) however it doesn't work.